# Should I run asynchronous code in an useEffect hook or in an action-creator-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am going through the tutorial of [react](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/) and Max discusses about action creator thunk in the Redux section . However the async code can be written in both useEffect hook and also using action-creator-thunk . Which approach will be better ? Will writing a separate action-creator-thunk instead of useffects give any extra benefit or performance gain  .

code for action-creator-thunk [cart-actions.js](https://github.com/academind/react-complete-guide-code/blob/19-advanced-redux/code/06-finished/src/store/cart-actions.js)

```
export const fetchCartData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://react-http-6b4a6.firebaseio.com/cart.json'
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Could not fetch cart data!');
      }

      const data = await response.json();

      return data;
    };

    try {
      const cartData = await fetchData();
      dispatch(
        cartActions.replaceCart({
          items: cartData.items || [],
          totalQuantity: cartData.totalQuantity,
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(
        uiActions.showNotification({
          status: 'error',
          title: 'Error!',
          message: 'Fetching cart data failed!',
        })
      );
    }
  };
};
```

code for [useEffect](https://github.com/academind/react-complete-guide-code/blob/19-advanced-redux/code/04-handling-http-states-feedback-with-redux/src/App.js)

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const showCart = useSelector((state) => state.ui.cartIsVisible);
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const notification = useSelector((state) => state.ui.notification);

  useEffect(() => {
    const sendCartData = async () => {
      dispatch(
        uiActions.showNotification({
          status: 'pending',
          title: 'Sending...',
          message: 'Sending cart data!',
        })
      );
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://react-http-6b4a6.firebaseio.com/cart.json',
        {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify(cart),
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Sending cart data failed.');
      }

      dispatch(
        uiActions.showNotification({
          status: 'success',
          title: 'Success!',
          message: 'Sent cart data successfully!',
        })
      );
    };

    if (isInitial) {
      isInitial = false;
      return;
    }

    sendCartData().catch((error) => {
      dispatch(
        uiActions.showNotification({
          status: 'error',
          title: 'Error!',
          message: 'Sending cart data failed!',
        })
      );
    });
  }, [cart, dispatch]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {notification && (
        <Notification
          status={notification.status}
          title={notification.title}
          message={notification.message}
        />
      )}
      <Layout>
        {showCart && <Cart />}
        <Products />
      </Layout>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which is better... is opinionated. It also depends on the specific use case, requirements, dev comfort & familiarity, team/project coding standards, etc... so much more than just the code alone. FWIW the functionality looks to be about the same so performance difference will be negligible. For code resuse, the code in the `useEffect` could be factored out into a function as well.

Comment: Its not correct to compare them IMO. useEffect and thunks both serve different purpose . When you are dispatching an action which performs an async tasks like making an API call then you need to use thunks because redux action creators just returns plain object and will not perform any side effects . useEffect on the other hand is no way connected to redux . So the question here is where to make the API call in thunk or in useEffect ? . so as @DrewReese mentioned it depends .

Comment: Mr Shyam . Max discusses about where should the side effects be executed (whether in useEffect or in action creator thunk . There are two different ways to do the same thing so my question is which one is better ? ) . Please attend the course first then give reply to me . [slide](https://github.com/academind/react-complete-guide-code/blob/19-advanced-redux/slides/slides.pdf)

Comment: Neither, or it's simply a matter of opinion which is "better". That's the point. Pick the one that works best for your current use case. Your question is rather more "Should I run asynchronous code in an `useEffect` hook or in an asynchronous action?"

Comment: @rajgopalbh4 Its a common practice to use thunk when you need to make api call and store the value in store and use useEffect to make API call to store the value in the component state . So in your case i would prefer to use `thunk` because you are updating the store .

Comment: Yes shyam . Now you are right .

Answer (score 3):

> However the async code can be written in both useEffect hook and also using action-creator-thunk . Which approach will be better ?

It depends on your requirements and architecture. Redux implements the [flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/).

The main difference between redux thunk and the `useEffect` approach is that a redux thunk can be dispatched from anywhere (not even a component) while the `useEffect` is bound to a component.

The redux thunk is easier to test, because it is isolated from the component. Of course you can also achieve better testing with the `useEffect` approach by extracting the logic into a separate function, but then your extracted function will become a "thunk-like" function.

Comment: Thank you . Rene . Yes Redux thunk wins the race . Agreed . you are 100% right  . Redux thunk can be dispatched from anywhere (not even a component) while the useEffect is bound to a component